# TPL Dataflow is either Parallel or Ordered but not both

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I have already posted various question recently regarding Async, Await, TPL and TPL Dataflow. All of these questions were answered making me understand these a lot.

I started looking into Asynchronous programming because I wanted to run my methods Asynchronous but there was a catch. I wanted to maintain the order when the tasks are run parallel asynchronously. The order needed to maintained when the records are inserted into the database and also when they are printed on the form using a `TextBox` control. (Here I am bounded to use `FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` because I am accessing the control from UI thread)

I was being suggested to use the TPL Dataflow because it was being told that it offers which I require. After a lot of struggle and understanding how TPL Dataflow works I managed to create a simple application which I am using to compare the performance between Synchronous call and TPL Dataflow code.

```
  private void btnStartSync_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();

        try
        {
            txtOutput.Clear();

            for (int i = 1; i <= 200; i++)
            {
                bool x = InsertIntoDatabaseSync(i);

                if (x)
                    txtOutput.Text += "Value Inserted for Id: " + i + Environment.NewLine;
                else
                    txtOutput.Text += "Value Failed for Id: " + i + Environment.NewLine;

                txtOutput.Refresh();
            }

            watch.Stop();
            lblSyncTime.Text = Convert.ToString(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

Above mentioned code is the Synchronous call to a Synchronous Method which inserts the records in the database.

```
 public async void btnTPLDataFlow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();

        txtOutput.Clear();

        ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions execOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions();
        execOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1;

        var transformBlock = new TransformBlock<string, OutputPropertyClass>(async v =>
        {
            try
            {
                bool x = await InsertIntoDatabaseAsync(Convert.ToInt32(v));

                OutputPropertyClass objResult = new OutputPropertyClass();
                objResult.Id = Convert.ToInt32(v);
                objResult.result = x;

                return objResult;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new Exception("Exception occurred for: " + v);
            }

        }, execOptions);


        ActionBlock<OutputPropertyClass> actionBlock = new ActionBlock<OutputPropertyClass>(v =>
        {
            try
            {
                if (v.result)
                    txtOutput.Text += "Value Inserted for Id: " + v.Id  + Environment.NewLine;
                else
                    txtOutput.Text += "Value Failed for Id: " + v.Id + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new Exception("Exception occurred");
            }                

        }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { TaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() });


        for (int i = 1; i <= 200; i++)
        {
            transformBlock.Post(i.ToString());
        }

        transformBlock.LinkTo(actionBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
        transformBlock.Complete();

        try
        {
            await transformBlock.Completion;
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


        watch.Stop();
        lblTPLDataFlow.Text = Convert.ToString(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000);
    }
```

The above mentioned code is a Async call DataFlow blocks. `TransformBlock` is calling the method `InsertIntoDatabaseAsync` which is a Async Task. Other then that `InsertIntoDatabaseAsync` and `InsertIntoDatabaseSync` are same.

Now both calls takes exactly same time to finish. On my system they both takes 9 seconds to finish.

To keep the order of the data in `TransformBlock` I have to limit the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to 1. This keeps the order but there is no gain in the efficiency.

If I try to increase the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` lets say 5 then the time taken for finish the process increases and it is more then 25 seconds. Also the order gets disturb.

I am looking for a way to both have order and parallelism. If TPL Dataflow can't achieve this then there must be some other way. Kindly help in finding the right direction.

Comment: You should probably `await actionBlock.Completion` instead of `await transformBlock.Completion`, because the last block in the pipeline is the `actionBlock`.

Answer (score 2):

What you want doesn't make sense. For every part of your flow a single part can never run in parallel if it needs to be ordered. When you limit everything to run in order it must run one at a time. This isn't an issue with TPL Dataflow, it's an issue with the requirement.

TPL Dataflow enables breaking the flow into multiple parts that each runs in parallel to the other and allowing for each part to run in parallel with itself (using `MaxDegreeOfParallelism > 1`) while keeping the flow itself in order.

TPL Dataflow keeps the input and output order for blocks, it doesn't keep the order inside the block (which is where you insert them to the database).

So, if you want all your flow to be both parallel and ordered TPL Dataflow can't help you, but nothing else can.

Comment: This was just a demo code which was written by me for the very first time for TPL DataFlow. I understand this scenario is not up to the mark but I was testing the performance as per my understanding. Alright I drop the requirement for keeping order inside the Block and I don't need the record in order. Having said that can I keep the order of values printed on TextBox?

Comment: @AdnanYaseen yes, and your code already does that because the `TransfromBlock` outputs item in the right order and your `ActionBlock` is single threaded (that's why I suggested that in the first place).

Comment: Thank you. Just a quick thing. Is there resource locking or race problem with TPL Dataflow? Do I need to handle this or it is not a problem. I am sorry if it is not a relevant question.

Comment: @AdnanYaseen If your code inside the block runs in parallel then it needs the same protection and synchronization like any other code. Other then that you don't need anything. You can both write and read from a block using multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

The trick with doing lots of things at the same time (parallel) is that they won't finish in the same order. To order a set of things, the set needs to be complete and not broken into separate tasks. You might need to order the set after the parallel tasks have all completed.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. So for example I have separate methods for performing a single task. Should I make them as one method in this case? And how do I combine UI Text Update with my Insert Method. UI Control is on separate Thread.